# UBUNTU 14.04 and WINDOWS 7

Tags: windows-7

My Toshiba Satellite P875-S7310 has the capacity for dual hard drives. I want Windows 7 on one. And Ubuntu 14.04 on my other hard drive. My question is in what order and how should I install these operating systems. I've done a lot of researching but none of the scenarios match mine. The last thing I want to do is have to wipe my hard drives and restart the process after trial and error 50 times. Please give me options and opinions as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you want. Personally I like to keep operating systems separated and each using their own boot manager, but that means pressing a few extra keys at boot up which can irritating if you switch between operating systems a lot.

**Option #1**

Install Windows 7, and then install Ubuntu. This will result in 1 boot manager (Grub2) which means when you boot up you will see Grub2 and be able to choose whether to boot Windows or Ubuntu. This makes it easier to boot the operating systems, but more complicated to replace them since they share a boot manager.

**Option #2**

Install Windows 7, remove the hard drive, install Ubuntu, and re-add the Windows 7 hard drive. This will result in each OSs being unaware of each other, and each using their own boot manager which is great if you ever replace 1 of the operating systems. When you turn the computer on it will automatically boot in Windows 7, no menu will be presented, but if you press the appropriate F# key at boot up you can use your quickboot menu to boot into Ubuntu instead by selecting to boot from the second hard drive. This option assumes your computer is capable of choosing which internal hard drive to boot from so if you go that route check your menu first to see if your system supports it.

Comment: you dont need to remove the hdd.

Comment: That is awesome! Just what I needed to see! I'm going to try option 1 in about an hour. Once the process is complete I will let you know what happens! Thanks again!

Comment: Hey so I wiped my hard drives and now I put in the windows 7 install dc and it freezes at the starting windows screen. What's up wih that?

Comment: The disc freezes, or a finished install freezes?

Comment: I believe the disc freezes. The loading logo just stops moving. I let it sit for about 30 minutes and nothing.

Comment: Does your disc have any major scratches? What OS did your computer come with?

Comment: No I have installed Windows 7 on one HDD and Ubuntu on the other HDD. Installation went fine, but Windows 7 needs CSM on to boot. and Ubuntu needs UEFI on to boot. Is there a way to dual boot these easier?